# Dynamically applying style to an element which is set with dangerouslySetInnerHTML in reactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Hi I have a scenario where I need to add this HTML content coming from server in an element and style the email address with blue color.

The HTML content coming from server::

```
"<p>139, Sethiwan Tower,<br>
10th Floor, Pan Rd,<br>
Silom, Bang Rak,<br>
Bangkok 10500,<br>
Thailand
<br/>
<br/>
<strong>Call us</strong> <br/>
(Service hotline) +66 2 430 4077
<br/>
<br/>
<strong>Send us an email</strong> <br/>
<a href="mailto:device-info@bolttech.co.th" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">device-info@bolttech.co.th</a></p>"
```

And I am setting this content in the frontend in a DIV tag like below::

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
```

I want to make the email address coming as red color.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.myClass > p > a {
  color: red;
}
```

```js
<div className="myClass" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
```

`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` will render `html` as if it were a child of your your `div`. So from there you just need to figure out the correct CSS selector to target the `a` element.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone stumbles upon this, and has a similar case as myself - dynamic color (js variable). You could do something like this:

```
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: html
          .replace(/<a /g, `<a style="color: ${dynamicColor};"`),
      }}
    />
```